# generate random values with a parabolic distribution

Tags: normal-distribution

I want to generate random delays between x and y. I want the ouputs to be around the middle of x and y more commonly than at x or y.

For example if my x is 10 and y is 20, I want the most common output to be 15.

I have been trying to solve this problem on paper but I am not a math genius, unfortunately.

I tried some formulas with Random.nextGuassian() but I simply cannot comprehend the odd output that it gives.

Comment: Answer would depend on the language, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you can implement a random number generator with a parabolic distribution you need to define what you mean by this. Here is one attempt:

[image: Parabolic distribution]

The distribution is defined on the interval 0 to 1 as a quadratic polynomial. On this interval the area below the curve has to be 1. By varying the parameters *K* and *M* you can adjust the distribution. *K* determines where the center of the parabola is located in the interval and *M* determines how far down to "pull" the parabola. In your question *K* is ½ as you want the apex to be in the middle of the interval. You did not specify *M*.

The parabola is specified by the function

> *f*(*x*) = *ax*<sup>2</sup> + *bx* + *c*

Provided *K* and *M* and that the area below the curve on the interval 0 to 1 should be 1 you need to compute *a*, *b* and *c*.

If *K* = ½ and *M* = ½ the exact solution is

> *f*(*x*) = 6*x*<sup>2</sup> - 6*x* + 2.

If this solution is not sufficient (because you want other values for *K* and/or *M*) then you will have to create a set of equations. Based on how the parabola is placed it is known that *a* has to be positive, *b* negative and *c* > *M*.

The apex of the parabola should touch (*K*, *M*). This means that *f*(*K*) = *M* or *f*(*K*) - *M* = 0.

For the apex to touch this point the discriminant of the modified quadratic equation has to be 0:

> *d'* = *b*<sup>2</sup> - 4*a*(*c* - *M*)

Provided that you know *a* and *c* you can calculate *b* (it is already known that *b* has to be negative to create the desired parabola):

> *b* = -√(4*a*(*c* - *M*))  [equation A]

The equation for the apex is:

> *f*(*K*) - *M* = *aK*<sup>2</sup> + *bK* + *c* - *M* = 0 [equation B]

The area below the parabola is computed from the definite integral over the interval 0 to 1 of *f*(*x*)

> ∫<sub>0</sub><sup>1</sup> *f*(*x*) *dx* = *a*/3 + *b*/2 + *c* = 1 [equation C]

You can substitute *b* from equation A into equation B and C giving two equations with two unknowns *a* and *c*. Unfortunately, these equations are non-linear and my math is getting rusty so I chose the "easy path" and used the Solver add-in in Excel to find approximate solutions for different values of *K* and *M*. If you take this approach you should probably add a constraint in the solver that *d'* cannot be negative as well as constraints on *a* and *c* as noted above.

Now that you know *a*, *b* and *c* for the desired parabolic equation the approach to create the random numbers with a parabolic distribution is as follows:

- Generate a random number on the domain of the parabolic equation with uniform distribution (visually you can think of this as generating a *y* value or an *f*(*x*) value)
- By using the inverse of *f*(*x*) compute the corresponding *x* value - notice that there are two possible solutions
- If one of the solutions is outside the interval 0 to 1 pick the other solution
- If both solutions are in the interval 0 to 1 pick one of them randomly

This solution picked is a random number with a parabolic distribution.

The inverse of *f*(*x*) is

> *x* = (-*b* ± √(*b*<sup>2</sup> - 4*a*(*c* - *y*)))/2*a*

Combining all this I have created a C# class. You will have to substitute the desired values for the parameters *K*, *M*, *a*, *b* and *c*. Or you can extend this code to compute *a*, *b* and *c* from *K* and *M* using numerical algorithms.

```
class ParabolicRandom
{
    const double k = 0.5D;
    const double m = 0.5D;

    const double a = 6;
    const double b = -6;
    const double c = 2;

    readonly double yMin = m;
    readonly double yMax = Math.Max(F(0D), F(1D));

    Random random;

    public ParabolicRandom() => random = new Random();

    public ParabolicRandom(int seed) => random = new Random(seed);

    public double Next()
    {
        var randomY = (yMax - yMin) * random.NextDouble() + yMin;
        var randomX1 = ReverseF1(randomY);
        var randomX2 = ReverseF2(randomY);

        if (randomX1 < 0D || randomX1 > 1D)
            return randomX2;
        if (randomX2 < 0D || randomX2 > 1D)
            return randomX1;
        return random.Next()%2 == 0 ? randomX1 : randomX2;
    }

    static double F(double x) => a * x * x + b * x + c;
    double ReverseF1(double y) => (-b + Math.Sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * (c - y))) / (2 * a);
    double ReverseF2(double y) => (-b - Math.Sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * (c - y))) / (2 * a);
}
```

To generate random number between 10 and 20 with half as many at 15 compared to 10 and 20 you can use it like this:

```
var lowerInclusive = 10;
var upperInclusive = 20;
var value = (int) Math.Floor(
    (upperInclusive - lowerInclusive + 1)*parabolicRandom.Next() + lowerInclusive);
```

Answer (score 1):

Java's `Random.nextGaussian()` returns values centered around a mean value of zero.  If you want the values to be centered on 15, then add 15 to the value returned by `Random.nextGaussian()`.  More generally, if you want the values to be centered halfway between `x` and `y` then do:

```
    delay = Random.nextGaussian + ( (x + y) * 0.5 );
```

In a normal distribution, 99.7% of the data samples lie within 3 standard deviations above and below the mean.  `Random.nextGaussian()` produces values whose standard deviation is 1.0, so if the mean is 15 then 99.7% of the values it returns will be between 12 and 18.  However, it will occasionally return values that are smaller than `x` or bigger than `y`, so you'll want to check for those cases.  Simply forcing values less than `x` to `x` and larger than `y` to `y` might be good enough for your use case:

```
    if (delay < x) { 
        delay = x;
    } else if (delay > y) {
        delay = y;
    }
```

References:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextGaussian()

Comment: I got this:  nr = r.nextGaussian() * (high - low) + ((high - low) / 2);

   if (nr > low && nr < high) //what I thought I wanted.
Now I see I was using the guassian improperly. Great Thanks!

Comment: How do I make this formula dynamic? When I do with a delta of 100 the distribution stays within like 7 values.

Comment: The likely range of the values is determined by the standard deviation, originally 1.0.  To expand the standard deviation by some factor F, multiply the value returned from `nextGaussian` by F.  Do that before adding the value that will shift the mean to your desired location.  The 99.7% spread is 6 standard deviations (3 above the mean, 3 below) so to get a spread of about 100 your multiplier F would be 100/6, or more generally `(high - low) / 6.0`.  (Divide by a floating-point value to avoid integer truncation in case `high` and `low` happen to be integers.)